# PHP Check of SQL query for value quantities

Tags: php, sql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a script where I am checking for values in a database.  There are 3 instances that I need to check for.

```
1) No value present
2) Single value exists
3) Multiple values exist
```

Currently, I have the following script to run for the first instance:

```
if($value){
echo ‘this is showing if a value exists’;
}else{
echo ‘this is showing if no value exists’;
}
```

How can I add to this to check if an array of values exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We would probably need to see the code that retrieves the data, but if you have an array of data you could just use `count`:

```
if (count($value) > 1) {
    // multiple values
}
```

You may also be using `SELECT COUNT` in which case you can just compare to that value:

```
if ($value["count"] > 1) {
```